# How do I go about building this application?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

So I have this application laid out but I am unsure on some aspects of how to go about it.

It's a website for dogs with cancer to supply a raw ketogenic diet for the user. There are other aspects of the website that I have figured out like where to hold state and such.

Where I'm a little confused on how to proceed is on the calculations for the ketogenic page shopping cart. The user can choose 1 fat source from the sources provided, one protein source and one green vegetable source. I want to make this as balanced and complete for the user for their dog- so obviously 1-protein 1 veg and 1 fat source is not balanced and complete. I need to factor in the amount of calories need per weight which I will have an input where the user can enter their dogs weight. I have done some of the math to make it complete and balanced on paper, factoring in amino acids, vitamins and minerals and the omega 6:3 ratio.

What I'm confused about is **where am I going to hold all this data** per se? It's a lot of data and it's based on many factors such as weight-activity, keto ratio like 1:1 or 2:1 depending what the user selects.

I obviously need a backend and need to build an API, but how would I return to the user the complete and balanced diet when so many other factors play in? Where would I store this other data? In objects? Variables? And then put it on the backend? I would greatly appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

how are you? First of all, congrats on the great idea, I think it is great.
For starters, I think it's important for you, to lay down what technologies you'll be using.

1- Choose the technologies you are going to use. Will you use the MERN stack? React for front-end, mongo for the database, node.js for back-end with express.js as a framework?

2- Will you be the one providing all the data for the dog's diets? If not, find some website with an API for that data.

3- I am not any kind of expert on JS nor React.js, I'm just following the logic here. But does that data change? or is it always the same? I would advise you to use objects, so you can "play" with them, pass them around the classes (I would advise you to create a react class, where you store all of those objects, make sure you export that class)

4- Just lay everything out and START BUILDING!!! It sounds hella overwhelming to start such a big project, but once you get going some i's will be dotted, you will get a better understanding of what you actually are going to build.

5- Few tips, if you use an API you won't need to store the data, else store it on your database (JSON file, for example, there are great youtube tutorials on how to do so.)
Keeping this in mind, you asked where you'll be storing all that data, if you have an api, you won't store anything, if you don't, JSON is your best shot, it's really easy and intuitive to use and easy to read inside a react component.

I hope this gave you some extra clarification on what you'll need to do, in order to start.

PS: This answer is purely based on my limited React (and web dev) experience, I am no expert, let me know if there's anything else I can help you with.

Comment: Thanks thats a big help for me. Im a fairly new programmer and this is a side project I want to do to add to my portfolio and also for my dog that lost her battle with cancer. To answer question yes I will be providing the data for the dog diets. Its just a little confusing because the user only selects from 3 options and I have to balance it which depends on weight, activity level and ketogenic ratio. I have pretty much figured out the math behind all this on paper. Its getting this from paper to coding where Im a little bit lost, I will use React,Redux, node.js and express. What  Mern stack?

Comment: @GeorgeHatzigeorgio I am very sorry for your loss man... 
 Have you heard about React states? Pretty much they let you pass information from one component to the next, kind of allowing you to pass all of that data from a dropdown menu to the user, it will be some sort of for loop, where you get the user input on that dropdown menu.
 The MERN stack is "Mongo db, Express.js, React.js, Node.js"

Tomascdmota#0946 
 Here is my discord, hit me up if you need more help, I am noob on this but I may be able to help on something.

Comment: Sounds good I am gi0rgi0 on discord . I will hit you up. Yea am very familiar with how react state works and the redux store to hold global state. I guess where I am really lost is getting it from paper to code if that makes sense, Since the data changes based on what the user puts in I guess throwing me for a loop. Because you could have one dog that weighs 30 lbs is sedentary and needs only 600 calories where you might have the same dog that weighs the same but is fairly active and needs an over calorie intake of 900 all this ever changing data is hell for me lol

Comment: Yes I understand, my tip is, just start doing. I'll be waiting, my friend. Have a good one